# A bijective "isometric" map $T:V \rightarrow V$ preserve inner product.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, inner-products

I don't see how [the first statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431119/bijective-map-preserving-inner-products-is-linear) holds. More precisely,

> Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$, $T:V \rightarrow V$ a bijective map such that $T(0)=0$ and $||Ty-Tx||= ||y-x||$. Then why is $\langle y,x \rangle = \langle Ty, Tx \rangle $?

I can prove that the real parts coincide, but not the imaginary parts since $T$ is not  assumed to be linear in $\mathbb{C}$. Perhaps this is not even true, is there a counter example?

Comment: As I recall, a theorem by Ulam-Mazur guarantees that a surjective isometry is linear.

Comment: The proof requires real vector space?

Comment: $V = \mathbb{C}$, $Tz = \overline{z}$.

Comment: However, I guess that in Kaplansky's setting inner products are bilinear, unlike what analysts call inner products in the case of complex vector spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel Fisher's comment.

What if $V = \mathbb C$ is the one-dimensional space with inner product $\langle x,y\rangle  = x\;\overline{y}$ .    Then $\|x\| = |x|$. Let $T$ be complex conjugation, $T(x) = \overline{x}$.
$$
\|Tx - Ty\| = |\overline{x}-\overline{y}| = |\overline{x-y}| = |x-y| = \|x-y\|
$$
Now try $x= i, y=1$, so that
$$
\langle y,x\rangle = y\;\overline{x} = 1\;\overline{i} = -i,
\\
\langle Ty,Tx\rangle = \overline{y}\;\overline{\;\overline{x}\;} = \overline{1}\;i = i
$$
are not equal.